# How do you UNhighlight a tab in the tab bar

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I have an app that has a tabbar at the bottom. When I select a tab the press is caught by:

```
didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

So, everything works great except that the tab stays blue until I hit another tab which stays blue until I hit another tab, etc....

is there  some code I can put in my switch/case code that turns the blue highlight back off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is the default behavior for UITabBars.  If you ***really*** want to change this default user-recognized behavior, I suggest going with a Custom toolbar instead.  Apple has done a great job with their UI elements by providing developers with the elements that iPhone users already know and understand.  It is **strongly advised** that you leave the UITabBar functionality as is.

Comment: I'm doing a "NEXT" on the bar. After it goes to the "next" it seems silly to have the button still on.

Comment: Looking through other apps I see what you mean. I'll leave it.